# Different Faces of Facebook

Tags: facebook, privacy

In Facebook, you have a Profile page which I it says is the Wall, and a Home page which says it's a news feed.  I'm confused as to which one other friends can see, and how much they can see.

I wonder if they can see everything my other friends post (thereby making me responsible for what they see on my Facebook page).

Can someone line it all out for me please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should consult the [help](http://www.facebook.com/help/?page=820) center.

> There are three types of content on
>   your Wall, and you can control who can
>   see them by following the instructions
>   below.
>
> **Posts your friends leave**. Posts, comments, and other things your
>   friends leave on your Wall are
>   controlled by a group of settings in
>   the "Sharing on Facebook" section on
>   the [Privacy Settings](http://www.facebook.com/settings/?tab=privacy) page. To
>   adjust these settings individually,
>   follow the "Customize settings" link
>   and scroll down to the "Things others
>   share" section.
>
> **Posts you create**. Status updates, photos, links and other things you
>   post are controlled by the "Posts by
>   Me" setting in the "Sharing on
>   Facebook" section on the [Privacy
>   Settings](http://www.facebook.com/settings/?tab=privacy) page. Follow the
>   "Customize settings" link to adjust
>   this setting individually. Keep in
>   mind the "Posts by Me" setting is a
>   just default for things you post. You
>   always have the option to adjust the
>   privacy for individual posts before
>   you share them by clicking the lock
>   icon directly from the Publisher.
>
> **Recent Activity**. These stories are determined by the privacy setting of
>   the content itself. For example, if
>   someone would already be permitted to
>   see a particular photo and comments,
>   then they would also be able to see
>   the Recent Activity story about you
>   making a comment on the photo. While
>   you cannot completely turn off recent
>   activity stories, you can remove a
>   particular story by clicking the
>   "Remove" button that appears to the
>   right of the story after you move your
>   mouse over it.

[Source - [Who can see my Wall?](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=16428) ]

In simpler terms your wall can only be seen by you and whatever friends you allow to see your wall.

Your news feed is what everyone allows you (based on your settings in their privacy page) to see.

Answer (score 3):

The things that show up on your Home page (your news feed) are determined by the permissions other people set first, and your preferences second.

**Other users cannot see your Home page.**

Your wall can be viewed by whatever privacy setting it is set to. I highly recommend you put it on "Friends Only".